# Qt is there something better then QMAKE_POST_LINK for post build actions?

Tags: qt, build

In my pro file I do somthing like:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$QMAKE_COPY $$quote($$PWD/*.xml) $$quote($$OUT_PWD) $$escape_expand(\\n\\t)
```

To copy files into the target area ready for deployment. This could be a default config file or some other resource.

When I build the code this works fine, the file is copied. However if I then modify the the config file (lets just call is `config.xml`) and re-build then since no source files are changed, the build returns "nothing to do ..." and therefore there is no post-linker stage and my updated `config.xml` file is not copied to the target area.

So to test my changes I have to modify a source file and then re-build... its a bit annoying and when I forget it often causes a few minutes of wasted time...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood well what you want to achieve, but is it something like this (from my personal project)?

```
unix:!macx {
LIBS += -ltag -L$$OUT_PWD/../Core/ -lmiam-core
    target.path = /usr/bin
    desktop.path = /usr/share/applications
    desktop.files = $$PWD/../../debian/usr/share/applications/miam-player.desktop
    icon64.path = /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps
    icon64.files = $$PWD/../../debian/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64    /apps/application-x-miamplayer.png
    appdata.path = /usr/share/appdata
    appdata.files = $$PWD/../../fedora/miam-player.appdata.xml
    INSTALLS += desktop \
        target \
        icon64 \
        appdata
}
```

So when you do:

```
qmake
make
make install
```

The install target will execute the 4 parts in INSTALL.

Edit: you can also add extra build steps in QtCreator:
[image]

Comment: That's quite good to know actually, +1 for that. But not quite what I am after. What I really wanted was a custom event that always occurs when I build the project. For example in Qt Creator when I press ctrl+b (which I think is equivalent to `qmake + make` but not the `make install` part, although I will check this tomorrow. Such that when I run the program in QtCreator (Ctrl+r) my configuration file is also copied to the build folder so that when my program runs it can read that latest configuration.

Comment: In Qt Creator you can add extra build steps:
[extra_build_step](http://i.imgur.com/brZuEDS.png)

Comment: I know, but if I recall, I am pretty sure that they only "run" if the compile runs. Remember I am not changing any source code (make says "nothing to do").

Comment: The other issue with that idea is that it is stored in the pro.user file which to me is no good as its not part of the config controlled files - i.e. if I check the project out on a different PC these settings are lost : (

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets: QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS. I've never used this one, but who knows?